# How to intercept and feed intra-layer output as target data

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

Sometimes we need to preprocess the data by feeding them through [preprocessing](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing) layers. This becomes problematic when your model is an autoencoder, in which case the input is both the x and the y.

Correct me if I'm wrong, and perhaps there's other ways around this, but it seems obvious to me that if the true input is, say, `[1,2,3]`, and I scale this to 0 and 1: `[0,0.5,1]`, then the model should be evaluating the autoencoder based on `x=[0,0.5,1]` and `y=[0,0.5,1]` rather than `x=[1,2,3]`. So if my model is, for example:

```
[
  preprocess_1,
  preprocess_2,
  encode1,
  ...
  decode1
]
```

How do I go about feeding the output of `[preprocess_1, preprocess_2]` to my model as `y`?

---

One obvious solution is to do the preprocessing before the model (for example, in tft's `preprocessing_fn`), but that has it downsides. For example, I'm guessing that doing this outside of the model means you won't get the full advantage of whatever GPU/accelerator the model has access to. Another reason would be that the [preprocessing](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing) package provides better support. Doing this outside of the preprocessing layers means you'd have to write some of the code yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to modify your loss function in order to minimize the difference between predictions and scaled inputs.

This can be done using [model.add_loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#add_loss).

Considering a dummy reconstruction task, where we have to reconstruct this data:

```
X = np.random.uniform(0,255, (300,10))
```

using this autoencoder:

```
inp = Input(shape=(10,))
prepocess_inp = Rescaling(scale=1./255)(inp)  # PREPROCESSING LAYER
x = Dense(64)(prepocess_inp)
x = Dense(16)(x)
x = Dense(64)(x)
out = Dense(10)(x)
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
```

You have to manually add the loss in this way, in order to take into account the preprocessing applied on the input data:

```
model.add_loss( tf.keras.losses.mean_absolute_error( prepocess_inp, out ) )
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=None)
```

The training is computed as usual:

```
model.fit(X, X, epochs=10, batch_size = 32)
```

Comment: I ran into a [related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71813366/how-to-add-loss-function-with-activity-regularizer-in-distributed-training) doing this. Wondering if you know how to solve it?