# How to add loss function with activity regularizer in distributed training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have an deep autoencoder with an activity_regularizer **in the bottleneck layer**:

```py
keras.layers.Dense(input_dim, ...)
...
keras.layers.Dense(2, activity_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l1())
...
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(input_dim, ...)
...
model.compile(loss='mse')
```

I then added some [tf2 preprocessing feature layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/migrating_feature_columns#feature_column_equivalence_table):

```py
inputs = {
  'a': keras.Input(shape=()),
  'b': keras.Input(shape=()), # some other preprocessing applied afterwards
}
preprocessed = keras.layers.Concatenate()(inputs.values())

keras.layers.Dense(input_dim, ...)(preprocessed)
...
keras.layers.Dense(2, activity_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l1())
...
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(input_dim, ...)
...
model.compile(loss='mse')
```

So now I can't just add a loss function like `model.compile(loss='mse')` since the input are raw features and the outputs are scalars. I need to compute the loss based on the output of `preprocessed` and the final `outputs`.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71614473/7242490) suggested I use the `model.add_loss()` function like:

```py
model.add_loss(keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()(preprocessed, outputs))
```

This worked but when I tried training this using `tf.distribute.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()` I got the error:

```
ValueError: Please use `tf.keras.losses.Reduction.SUM` or `tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE` for loss reduction when losses are used with `tf.distribute.Strategy` outside of the built-in training loops. You can implement `tf.keras.losses.Reduction.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE` using global batch size like:

with strategy.scope():
    loss_obj = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)
    ....
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(loss_obj(labels, predictions)) * (1. / global_batch_size)

Please see https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/custom_training for more details.
```

Reading https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/custom_training the documentation states:

> If you are using regularization losses in your model then you need to scale the loss value by number of replicas. You can do this by using the tf.nn.scale_regularization_loss function.

So I'm now a bit confused. Does the above statement apply to the `activity_regularizer` I added? How does this work with the `global_batch_size`?

How can I solve this in distributed training?

---

**TLDR: Do I need to "scale the loss value by number of replicas" when using hidden layer `activity_regularizer` in distributed training?**